# Orientdb upsert using java

Tags: java, orientdb

i have a document in  orient db  like

```
{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"}
```

how can i update the value of b if c is 3  using java

i need to execute the  below query  using java

```
UPDATE <document name >Merge {"a":25"} where c=3
```

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ODatabaseDocumentTx db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx(path);
db.open("root","root");
db.command(new OCommandSQL("update <document name > set a=30 where c=3")).execute();
```